# Is there a way to troubleshoot Wake on LAN on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan

1. I have an Asus Republic of Gamers laptop connected to a physical lan with a cable.
2. I have recorded the MAC address of the network interface:

```
ipconfig /all

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.30)
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-60-6E-12-7E-72
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

3. I enbabled wake on lan in the **Device Manager**:

[image: device manager]

4. The I put the computer in **Sleep** mode:

[image: Sleep]

Unfortunately, I am unable to wake up the computer from two other (mac and Linux) machines on the same network, connected physically to the same switch:

```
$ wakeonlan 08:60:6E:12:7E:72
Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9 with 08:60:6E:12:7E:72
```

I went through my entire BIOS but I haven't found anything relaated to power management, wake on lan, waking from PCI, etc…

Is there a way to debug this? (Detect the presence of the magic packets, etc.)

Thanks!

Comment: Ensure firmware/BIOS/eufi are configured to allow WOL and disable all the S# modes if there's such an option. Disable hibernation on windows via `powercfg hibernate off` elevated command prompt and don't put the OS to sleep or disallow if possible. I UNcheck that only allow magic packet in my configs that WOL works. Ensure your clients can get the udp 7 or 9 packets you send out on the broadcast to the mac addresses via routers/switches along the path where you send WOL from. I also ensure fast user/switch mode is disabled and wait for full network before login. Update NIC drivers to latest.

Answer (score 1):

If your are able to wake up your other computers using WOL broadcasts, then it is unlikely that you have an issue with broadcasting the magic packets. The only way to know for sure is to run a packet logger/analyzer.

It is unlikely that it is a broadcast problem and it's almost always software setting, driver compatibility issue or BIOS configuration issue.

1. Your BIOS almost certainly has a setting to control Wake On Lan. Asus often uses confusing names for this function so you may have missed it. It is usually in BIOS under Advanced, APM Management and then it will be called Power on By PCI/PCIE.  Asus has this turned off by default most of the time. So that's your first place to check.
2. In your screenshot for the adapter, check the Advanced tab and check all the subcategories that might relate to Wake On Lan. Depending on the driver you could see options for Wake On Pattern Match, Shutdown Wake On Lan, etc...
3. On older systems, Windows Fast StartUp can interfere with Wake On Lan.  Try disabling that if enabled (located in Control Panel>Power Options>System Settings)
4. Bad Network Driver - try updating or try alternate drivers for your network adapter.
5. Your sleep and suspend state could be affecting it. Try changing from S3 to S5 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Check the advanced options in the BIOS ([see here](https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?12627-Set-up-Wake-On-Lan)).

You can use [any WOL packet sniffer](https://www.ecosia.org/search?tt=mzl&q=wol%20sniffer%20windows%2010) to check if the magic packets arrive, I myself use Wireshark.

A good way to troubleshoot is to check if wake via USB/Keyboard/etc. works. Depending on the result I would try those options first:

- make sure to use the driver specific to the network chip on the mainboard, don't use Window's generic driver and update if possible.
- Currently you are using S3 (suspend to RAM) try other suspend states
  as well, S4 (suspend to disk) or S5 (shut down) - mind the quick restart option in Win10 for S5.